# Can we call Java Method from linux Shell Script or Crontab?

Tags: java

Can we call Java Method from Linux Shell Script?
I tried using setting path of java and class in script.
Please help.

Comment: No. Unless you mean `main`; in which case yes. Multiple Java classes can contain a `main` method.

Comment: Or, you might be able to hack something together with `jshell`. But I haven't done so.

Comment: You could call the `main` function and hand over parameters or call the custom function from the `main`function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly execute any method from a shell script. You'll need to have that method exposed externally in some way. You can write a main method that directly invokes the code you want.

You can use shell script and call your java program like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
JAVA_HOME=<java-home-path> 
CLASSPATH=<classpath>

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $CLASSPATH JavaClassName 
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call the `main` function and hand over parameters or call the custom function from the `main`function. When there is a .jar file, you can run it using:

```
java -jar <pathToJarFile> <parameters>
```